# Nothing is returned when connecting to MySQL database using PyMySQL (using 'self' variable)

Tags: mysql, self, pymysql

I am trying test out the db connection to MySQL database using PyMySQL.   I have been trying to put this into a class, but running into problems where the script is now returning nothing.  This is my first time using the 'self' variable.

1. I have a database table called 'items', with the following attributes:

   [image]
2. My original code is written as follows:

   ```
   import pymysql.cursors

   #Connect to the database
   connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
       user='root',
       password='',
       db='testDB',
       charset='utf8mb4',
       cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

   try:
       with connection.cursor() as cursor:
       #Read a single record
       sql = "SELECT * FROM items"
       cursor.execute(sql)
       result = cursor.fetchone()
       print(result)

   finally:
       connection.close()
   ```

This script runs fine and returns the following result: 
{'id': 2}

3. I have been trying to put this code into a class, where I am now using 'self', but running into problems where the script returns nothing.

   ```
   import pymysql.cursors

   class mySQLTest(object):

       def __init__(self):
           self.conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                                user='root',
                                password='',
                                db='testDB',
                                charset='utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
           self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

       def test(self):
           try:
               with self.cursor:
                   sql = "SELECT * FROM items"
                   self.cursor.execute(sql)
                   result = self.cursor.fetchall()
                   print(result)

           finally:
               self.conn.close
   ```

When I run this script, nothing is returned (I would expect that values 2,3,4,5 be returned).  It simply states: 'Process finished with exit code 0'.

I think I am doing something wrong when I am defining the function?  Appreciate any help/guidance.

Comment: Is this your whole script? Then you just have defined your class up to now (e.g. what it would do if you WOULD run it). You have to run your class (create an instance and use it). You should have a look at a tutorial, e.g.: [What is a class? Think of a class as a blueprint. It isn't something in itself, it simply describes how to make something.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner%27s_Python_Tutorial/Classes)

Comment: @Solarflare - I am a newbie to Python, so thank you for the tutorial.  I ran the class (created an instance, and was able to run the 'test' method.  It returned the list of values as expected.  For future reference, I ran the class in Python console (PyCharm CE)